# getting a invalid_request_body error when i try to void a document

Tags: java, docusignapi

When trying to void a in-progress document, I received the invalid_request_body error(The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Data at the root level is invalid). Is there something missing on the request body ?

```
       url = baseURL + "/envelopes/" + envelopeId;  
       body = "";       

        // re-use connection object for second request...
        conn = InitializeRequest(url, "PUT", body, authenticationHeader);

        String requestBody = "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" +
                "Accept: application/xml" +                                
                            "Content-Type: application/xml\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            body + "\r\n\r\n--BOUNDARY\r\n" +   
            "status: voided\r\n" + 
            "voidedReason: Time-out\r\n" + 
            "\r\n";
        String reqBody2 = "\r\n" + "--BOUNDARY--\r\n\r\n";

        DataOutputStream dos= new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
        dos.writeBytes(requestBody.toString());
        //dos.write(bytes);
        dos.writeBytes(reqBody2.toString()); 
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();


        System.out.println("STEP 2:  Retrieving envelope information for envelope " + envelopeId + ".\n");
        status = conn.getResponseCode(); // triggers the request
        if( status != 200 ) { // 200 = OK
            System.out.println(conn);
            System.out.println(status);
            errorParse(conn, status);
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        // display results 
        response = getResponseBody(conn);
```

Comment: request body## String requestBody = "<envelope>" +
                                 "<status>voided</status>" +
                                 "<voidedReason>user   aborted</voidedReason>" +
                                 "</envelope>";
easier way! atleast for me..and it works well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up with your comments for the benefit of the community...

This is the request body that worked for you in the end:

```
request body## String requestBody = "<envelope>" + "<status>voided</status>" + "<voidedReason>user aborted</voidedReason>" + "</envelope>"
```